# Getting all the words except the last one from a string

Tags: vba

I am trying to get all the words except the last one from a name specified in an excel cell. For some reason my simple VBA code will not run; it just gives me back the original name as is. Could someone please help explain why?

```
Function GetName(Source As String)
    Dim arr() As String 'declares a dynamic array
    arr = VBA.Split(Source, " ") 'an array of words split by space from the Source string is built
    'Ubound function gets the last position of items in the array
    Name = ""

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Name = Name + " " + arr(i)
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

You are including the entire array in the output - you need to stop before the last element...

Also your code as posted doesn't return any value

```
Function GetName(Source As String)
    Dim arr() As String 'declares a dynamic array
    arr = VBA.Split(Source, " ") 'an array of words split by space from the Source string is built
    'Ubound function gets the last position of items in the array
    GetName = ""

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1 '<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        GetName = GetName + " " + arr(i)
    Next i

End Function
```

Alternative approach:

```
Function GetName(Source As String) As String
    Dim arr, v
    v = Trim(Source)
    If Len(v) > 0 Then
        arr = VBA.Split(v, " ")
        If UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) > 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1) '<< remove last element
            GetName = Join(arr, " ")
        Else
            GetName = v
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Ah yes, that worked. But now the value returned is a zero instead of the actual output? How do i return the final answer into the cell when called?

Comment: Thanks so much for answering btw!

Comment: If you're expecting to return a string then specify the return type on your function.  See my second suggestion for something which has some error checking, though you may want to change how it handles single words (just return that one word, or nothing?)

Comment: What's the purpose of `GetName = ""`?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks that makes sense, I will try that approach.

Comment: @JohnyL the function is supposed to return a string which includes all the words from the source except the last one. e.g. with source "I am fine" GetName should return "I am"

Comment: @TimWilliams If I may bother again: I used the second version of your code (thank you!) but the excel gives me a #VALUE! error.

Comment: In all cases, or just with some specific inputs?  That exact code works fine for me.

Comment: In all cases apparently. Even when i add in string manually or input a cell. I copy pasted the code so it should work just fine

Comment: Try calling the function from a sub:  E.g. - `Sub tester(): Debug.Print GetName("a b"): End Sub`  That will let you debug any errors in your code

Comment: I just did and it says runtime error, Type mismatch at the following line:

Comment: arr = VBA.Split(v, " ")

Comment: @Mrizwan This is unnecessary line

Comment: isnt it used to create the array in the first place though?

Comment: @JohnyL - why do you think it's unnecessary?

Comment: as written (i.e. without the declared return type), all it does is make the `GetName` identifier a `Variant/String`. With the declared return type it's superfluous, since a `String` is initialized to an empty string anyway. I think that's what @JohnyL meant to point out.

Comment: That said I'd use the `&` string concatenation operator instead of `+` here, but the `join` approach is much more solid anyway.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes, this is what I ment. Without `GetName = ""`, if the `If` loop wouldn't be run, the `GetName` would be `Empty`, but any string manipulation would convert it to zero-length string.